# Why does this compile with "Is" but not with "IsNot"?

Tags: vb.net

I'm hacking some old VB code, and I want a function to return early if an exception is caught, but if it's a `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` the function should continue. Just so I don't get [XY'ed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), I know this is a strange requirement, but I'm rewriting the code in C#, and I just need to see the result of this. I know there's probably a better way to do it. Here is the original code:

```
Try
    doSomeStuffWithFiles(files)
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Far Field: error in reading / writing to far field file." & Chr(13) & ex.Message)
    Exit Sub
End Try
```

So I added a couple lines:

```
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Far Field: error in reading / writing to far field file." & Chr(13) & ex.Message)
    If TypeOf ex IsNot System.UnauthorizedAccessException Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Try
```

Now, I'm not an expert in VB, but as far as I can tell this is perfectly valid VB. It also exactly matches the sample code for `TypeOf` on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ec5kw18.aspx). However, this code fails to compile. I get this error:

```
Error   21  'Is' expected.  C:\FilePath 3114    26  Project
Error   22  'UnauthorizedAccessException' is a type in 'System' and cannot be used as an expression.    C:\FilePath 3114    32  Project
```

If I change that line to

```
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Far Field: error in reading / writing to far field file." & Chr(13) & ex.Message)
    If TypeOf ex Is System.UnauthorizedAccessException Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Try
```

Then everything compiles and runs fine. (Sans the logic being backwards)

I am using visual studio 2013, and targeting .net framework 2.0.

So what's the reason that `IsNot` is not valid?

Comment: Could you add some information on Visual Studio version and Framework version used to build your project?

Comment: Should be `If Not TypeOf ex Is System.UnauthorizedAccessException`. Short answer: **The IsNot operator cannot be used to compare expressions returned from the TypeOf operator. Instead, you must use the Not and Is operators.** See [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3bat82c.aspx)

Comment: Prior to VS2015, the `TypeOf var Is` syntax is all that is supported.  see: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ec5kw18(v=vs.120).aspx#Anchor_1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ec5kw18(v=vs.120).aspx#Anchor_1)

Comment: @TnTinMn I'd upvote that as an answer

Comment: @CoderDennis, thanks but the real question of the OP should be: "How to use the documentation?"  as after reading the question, I see that there is a link to the most recent documentation version.  OP just in case you are not aware of it, you can click on the "Other Versions" drop-down in the documentation to see earlier documentation.  At one time, doing so was prudent to do so that you could view the "Community Additions" section that has been missing in the more recent versions.

Comment: @Codexer Thanks for all your help. I am not sure I understand your last comment. How would you have written the comparison?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem it's mentioned in my comment above...

Comment: Seeing all these comments about versions in which I disagree should not matter on what Microsoft does down the road; they only made it easier. The real problem is the way he was doing the comparison. It first has to determine if the object pointed at the `TypeOf` is really what he's comparing it too. Under the hood it makes a cast for the comparison, but when joined with an `IsNot` can be problematic...in which he did have. If the object isn't what the comparison is `TypeOf` the `IsNot` operator is not valid as the return type can't be evaluated...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would work as you have it in Visual Studio 2015, but if you look at the [VS2013 version of the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ec5kw18(v=vs.120).aspx), you'll see only `TypeOf ... Is` listed, so you'd need to use `Not TypeOf ... Is`.

Target .NET Framework version doesn't make a difference. If you're using VS2015, `TypeOf ... IsNot` will compile.

Answer (score 0):

`IsNot` didn't exist in pre `2.0 .Net` `VB.Net`

```
If Not TypeOf ex Is
```

This syntax came from `vb6`

Comment: That may be what is needed, but OP is not "pre 2.0 .Net" so reason isn't correct.